# How to use the output binding of spring-cloud-stream in unit tests?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using spring cloud stream to modify a Kafka Topic and write the resulting data with ".toTable()" to a table. In the application.yaml I will set the input and output bindings.
This works fine on the Kafka cluster but not with my current test setup.

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectTopology {

    @Bean
    public static Serde<Object> objSerde() {
        return new ProtobufSerde<>(Object.parser());
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, Object>, KTable<String, Object>> obj() {

        return objKStream -> objKStream
                .transform((TransformerSupplier<String, Object, KeyValue<String, Object>>) SomeTransformer::new)
                .toTable();
    }
}
```

application.yaml:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings:
    obj-in-0:
        destination: input-name
    obj-out-0:
        destination: output-name
```

How would I access the KTable generated by "toTable" in the code below? Is there a way to use the spring-cloud-stream bindings in my unit tests?

```
ObjectTopology objectTopology = new ObjectTopology();
StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

Serde<String> keySerde = Serdes.String();
Serde<Object> valueSerde = objSerde();

KStream<String, Object> objKStream = streamsBuilder.stream("input-topic-name", Consumed.with(keySerde, valueSerde));

objectTopology.obj().apply(objKStream);

TopologyTestDriver topologyTestDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(streamsBuilder.build());

TestInputTopic<String, Object> objTestInputTopic = topologyTestDriver.createInputTopic("input-topic-name", keySerde.serializer(), valueSerde.serializer());
KeyValueStore<String, Object> objStore = topologyTestDriver.getKeyValueStore("???"); // I would like to use the name defined by the output binding in application.yaml "output-name"

Object object = createObject();

objTestInputTopic.pipeInput("elem_0", object);

Object result = objStore.get("elem_0");
assertThat(result).isEqualTo(object);
```

Comment: I don't think the state store name is given from the binder name. You should use Materialized class in your obj function to provide a name

Comment: for the naming: https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#toTable-- and have you looked at `topologyTestDriver.createOutputTopic`?

Answer (score 0):

`toTable` creates an internal topic. You should probably use topologyTestDriver.createOutputTopic to read it.

For the naming, there is https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#toTable--